# Date_trunc error to truck the user activity on website

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using google cloud and trying to format the event_timestamp column to extract the date and time to identifying time that user take to make a purchase on website

```
DATE_TRUNC(DATE (event_timestamp), 'month') AS purchase_date,
```

as per the query, I got an error "A valid date part name is required at [6:31]"

the dateset

| event_timestamp |
| --- |
| 1605430896492843 |

expecting results example

| Purchase_date |
| --- |
| 2020-11-15 12:27:20 |

Answer (score 1):

Since your event_timestamp value consists of 16 digits, you need to use the `timestamp_micros` function.

> [timestamp_micros](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_micros) Interprets int64_expression as the number of microseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and returns a timestamp.

```
select timestamp_micros(event_timestamp) AS purchase_date
```

This will output (2020-11-15 09:01:36.492843 UTC) for the input (1605430896492843).

The `date_trunc /timestamp_trunc` function will truncate the date to the given date_part, so according to your expected output you don't need to use it.

```
select timestamp_trunc(timestamp_micros(1605430896492843), month) AS purchase_date
```

This will output (2020-11-01 00:00:00 UTC)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc) it seems, that it should be without quotes:

```
DATE_TRUNC(DATE (event_timestamp), MONTH) AS purchase_date
```

Comment: I have tried already, but also get error

Answer (score 0):

Change the order:

```
DATE_TRUNC('month', DATE (event_timestamp)) AS purchase_date
```